# Could not initialize class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.BeanValidationHelper

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc, jaxb

I have been trying to get a dto object in json format as a response from my webservice. Webservice is developed in Spring Framework. But, whenever I try to access my application either from curl or from browser it gives me following exception on server-side.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.BeanValidationHelper

My dto is something like this:

```
public class UserDto {
  @JsonProperty 
    private String id;
  @JsonProperty
    private String userRole;
//.... Getter & Setters skipped
}
```

My controller method is like:

```
    @GET
    @Path("getUser")
    @Produces({"application/xml",MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public  UserDto GetLoggedinUser() {
        return new UserDto("wasif kirmani");
    }
```

I don't know where am I going wrong?

Environment:
Server: GlassFish 4.1.1
Java: 6EE

Comment: This seems to be a bug in glassfish 4.1.1 as per the JIRA https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21440. you  can look out for a solution/work around.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a missing dependency in your project.  Try to adding this dependency to your pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is the EclipseLink project for Object-XML binding and JAXB implementation. This also includes JSON binding support.

Reference: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Maven